# ASP.Net MVC4 configuration error after installing MySQL Connector .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a MVC4 web application project.When i'm using empty project and simply run it on browser it works fine.But the problem is when i'm trying to create a Internet application project instead of Empty project.Once i created internet application project and when trying to run it on browser it shows following configuration error.As i understood it's something related to MySQL connector assembly reference.Anyhow following is the error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service    this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web.v20, Version=6.9.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 265:      <providers>
Line 266:        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
Line 267:        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web.v20, Version=6.9.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
Line 268:      </providers>
Line 269:    </membership>

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 267 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.Web.v20, Version=6.9.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.
```

Comment: It looks like someone changed machine.config instead of site's web.config - find out who and ask why it was done... Otherwise make sure to carefully read information in  "The following information can be helpful to determine why..." section of error message.

Comment: No no one changed it.Because i just created the project and tried to run it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is not how one installed/created by .Net install (or Windows install, depending on version) looks like. So someone or something changed the machine.config file. If you don't care - just remove that line and it should fix *your* problem (possibly breaking something else that made the change...).

Comment: You mean to remove the line from web.config file?

Comment: I'm confusing why it works fine for empty project and not for internet application project.

Comment: Because one reads the element and tries to instantiate objects while other does not.

Comment: OK.I understood.Can you please tell me what should i do to avoid from this issue?I checked this issue on internet, but didn't found a solution.

Comment: Remove that line - you can always put it back if needed (also I don't think it should be in machine level config to start with). If not enough update your question/or ask new one with new error.

Comment: OK.Can you please tell me from which file i should remove this?I'm bit confused because i couldn't find this in web.config file.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This nasty error occurs when you install MySQL .NET Connector 6.9.4 (probably other versions too) because if you do not uncheck "Web Providers" during the installation it writes in your machine.config which brings you to this error. Be sure to read the entire answer before applying any of these steps in order to start from where you have to start.

The real problem with other suggestions is that if you are not using MySQL in every project to just add a reference to MySQL dll to mitigate the problem in every project is not an option. Every project of yours that uses ASP.NET will require it because of the rows added in machine config by the installer!

To solve the problem properly :

1. Start the installer and click "Change"
2. then remove the "Web Providers" section entirely.
3. This will remove the declarations from your machine.config (which I find a horrible thing to do in installer but the installer creates them without any notification anyway).
4. After that it is a good idea to check you machine config which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325492/1042934). And be sure that it did not spoil both [32 and 64 machine configs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447936/updating-net-4-0-machine-config-seems-to-have-no-effect).
5. When your machine config is clear add the MySql.Web assembly to your project and add the MySQLMembershipProvider declaration in your project web.config - the standard procedure.
6. Enjoy the clean installation of MySQL connector.

But if you do it that way you may try to add Ado NET Entity Data model after, right? If that is the case it is most likely that you do not see the option for MySQL as an available data source in the wizard. This is because from version 6.7 when you install MySQL Connector .NET it will no longer [register as DDEX provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb163935.aspx) automatically.

To correct this issue you have to download a separate installer provided especially for MySQL and .NET from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html) or the just Visual Studio integration plug-in directly from [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)

Be **sure** to check the *Visual Studio integration* and *connector* during the installation wizard on either of the above installers.

Comment: Thanks for your long description.I'll try this.

Comment: Perfect! You saved me hours of headache.

Comment: thank you! I was getting really frustrated with this and your solution worked perfectly! +1

Comment: Thank you! I first installed with **Web Providers** then without it so my `machine.config` is also edited by the installer but the install is not rollbacked!

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked for me:

```
<siteMap>
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
```

I think they forgot to put the file MySql.Web in de GAC (Global Assembly Cache)

Comment: If you do not correct the root of the problem, which is the snippet inserted by the installer in your machine.config you will have to copy-paste this on every solution you make on your developer machine.

Comment: For some reason, the issue only happens in some of my solutions, so this works for me in the few solutions where it is happening.  Also, the <sitemap> section goes in the <system.web> section

Answer (score 4):

-Open the MySQL installer
-Click the remove tab to your right.
-Check all the things that are related to .Net (like connectors)
-Click remove button
-Close and reopen visual studio
-Upvote Ognyan Dimitrov's answer

Comment: Unistalling .net connectors isn't really a solution when you need to use MySQL in your other projects...

Answer (score 4):

There is another solution: I manually opened machine.config and commented out section `<Sitemap>` (it's almost on the bottom of the file). Save it as the administrator and violá. It works.

Solutions using sitemaps are intact without having to touch them and my solutions where I need to use the MySQL connector work as expected as well.

Answer (score 1):

finally I have solved it my own and it was a small solution. Just have to add a reference to `Web.Mysql` dll file and now it works properly.

Comment: No an option if your project is not MySQL dependent. Every project of yours will be dependent on this assembly and whenever you use ASP.NET roles you will have to include this assembly!

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a while ago, but what worked for me was adding the `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Web` references to my project.

Answer (score -1):

just install latest MySql .Net Connector and select 'Complete' install, it will fix your problems.